# How to open/inspect data stored in .thumbdata3 files?

Tags: thumbnails

A THUMBDATA file is a cache file created by some Android devices' Gallery app. It contains indexed property information about every thumbnail image shown in Gallery.
I accidentally lost all my images on my phone and all I have is some files named: x.thumbdata3-xxxx they sized about 1-1.5GB each.
the question is how can I extract the data inside these files? **I Don't care if they tiny sized or anything**. I managed to install some apps on android and extracted a couple of images but all the data extracted was not even close to 2MB. is there any solution for this? *not looking for any sort of online tools. Thanks.